# Irregular Trigger BizTalk Scheduled Task Adapter

Tags: scheduled-tasks, biztalk, biztalk-2016

I have several receive locations of type schedule in a BizTalk 2016 server. All except one work fine. This one has been getting triggered as defined in the schedule daily at 04:00 am, however it suddenly began to start at 05:00 pm and one day it didn´t run.

There is no Error Log in the Application Logs or the SQL Logs. The Receive Location is enabled. The Server Time is correct.

Does anyone has a hint, what this behavior might be caused by?

- BTS 2016
- Scheduled Task Adapter 6.0.0.6

Answer (score 1):

The current version is 7.0.2. and that includes some fixes

e.g.

- [In certain cases task won't trigger in set time with Timespan with Biztalk 2016](https://github.com/sandroasp/BizTalk-Scheduled-Task-Adapter/issues/5)
- [Timly Schedule Start Time (and Date) doest not work correct](https://github.com/sandroasp/BizTalk-Scheduled-Task-Adapter/issues/4)

So I would suggest downloading and installing 7.0.2.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced a similar behavior when the Host Instance is shared and sometimes overloaded. Try to dedicate a HI for scheduling only. And as suggested by @Dijkgraaf, you can use the last version of this Adapter